# In LWJGL's OpenCL capabilities where do I derive "cl_platform_id" from?

Tags: java, opencl, lwjgl

Taking a look at the [LWJGL docs](https://javadoc.lwjgl.org/org/lwjgl/opencl/CLCapabilities.html) for their OpenCL port, one can see that in order to create the OpenCL capabilities using the method `createPlatfromCapabilities` in the `CL.class` class, you'll need to pass in a long `cl_platform_id`. Where is this derived?

I've tried passing in `Platform.WINDOWS`, as seen below:
[image]
However, there is no field in `Platform.WINDOWS` that will yield a long.

Considering the variable is named "platform" ID, I imagine it's not asking for a window long that LWJGL normally issues, and because "CL" is also in the name, I assume that It's also issued by one of the internal OpenCL classes.

I've searched the docs extensively, and "`cl_platform_id`" only appears in that method. The docs simply say the following:

> "@param cl_platform_id: the platform to query"

Gee. that helps a lot.

What does the `cl_platform_id` parameter in the `createPlatfromCapabilities` method signify, and where would I find it?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a platform ID obtained from [clGetPlatformIDs](http://legacy.lwjgl.org/javadoc/org/lwjgl/opencl/CL10.html#clGetPlatformIDs(org.lwjgl.PointerBuffer,%20java.nio.IntBuffer)). The first parameter is a buffer to store the IDs in (or `null`) and the second parameter is a buffer to store the number of IDs read (or `null`). You'll want to call the function once passing `null` for the first parameter and a 1-item `IntBuffer` for the second, then use the int stored in the buffer to allocate a `PointerBuffer` and call it again to actually read the IDs.